# Nightwatch : An occurred error while retrieving a new session

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

In my react project, I would like to use nightwatch as testing tool. I'm actually using Nightwatch v1.0.4 and selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar on windows.

And this is my config (**nightwatch.json**) :

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "tests"
  ],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "custom_commands_path": "",
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "page_objects_path": "",
  "globals_path": "",
  "disable_colors": false,
  "test_workers": false,
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 4444,
    "server_path": "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar",
    "log_path": "./logs",
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "./bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "acceptSslCerts": true
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "webdriver": {
        "server_path": "./bin/chromedriver",
        "cli_args": [
          "--log",
          "debug"
        ]
      },
      "disable_colors": false,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "request_timeout_options": {
        "timeout": 60000,
        "retry_attempts": 5
      },
      "default_path_prefix" : "",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "acceptInsecureCerts": true
      }
    },
    "chrome": {
      "webdriver": {
        "port": 9515,
        "default_path_prefix": "",
        "server_path": "./bin/chromedriver",
        "cli_args": [
          "--verbose"
        ]
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "loggingPrefs": {
          "driver": "INFO",
          "server": "OFF",
          "browser": "INFO"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my test file (**tests/index.js**):

```
const host = 'http://localhost:3000'

module.exports = {
    'Demo test' : function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://google.com')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .pause(5000)
            .end();
    }
}
```

When I run `nightwatch`, it gives me the following error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please ?

Comment: What is your Chrome and ChromeDriver version?

Comment: Chrome : v65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) & ChromeDriver : v2.9

Comment: ChromeDriver version

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm using 32bit because I didn't find 64 bit one (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your ChromeDriver version -which you've mentioned as `v2.9` is pretty old.

As of the ChromeDriver download [page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), as per your Chrome version, you should use ChromeDriver version above `2.36` - I would recommend the latest `2.38`

Comment: I've changed ChromeDriver version to 2.37, then 2.38 but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try setting `start_process": false,` and also check if the standalone version is 3.11.

Comment: I updated start_process to `false` and this is what I get : [Index] Test Suite
==================
    POST  /session - ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
   An occurred error while retrieving a new session: "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444" at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)